# VariableSizedWrapGrid for jQuery

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins

I looking for [Windows8 VariableSizedWrapGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid) counterpart in jQuery/html+css to display fixed height, horizontal scrolled panel that contains its items from top to bottom and then from left to right.